# apache2 - runs python 2.6, instead of 2.7

Tags: apache, python-2.7, virtualenv, wsgi, python-2.6

I'm trying to set up apache2 web server for Odoo. The only problem I got is it does not run correct version of python. I'm using squeez linux distribution, so default version is 2.6. But I need 2.7. So I installed it separately and I could run it using virtualenv just fine (before I had set Odoo server using that approach). Now I need to do the same, but also need to introduce apache2. But for some reason it always runs python 2.6 and with that Odoo (v8) fails to start, because it requires python 2.7.

So when I start apache2 and try to open server address, I get this error:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=32341): Target WSGI script '/opt/odoo/openerp-wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=32341): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/odoo/openerp-wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/odoo/openerp-wsgi.py", line 22, in <module>
     import openerp
   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
     import modules
   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
     from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/graph.py", line 32, in <module>
     import openerp.osv as osv
   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/osv/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
     import osv
   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 23, in <module>
     from .orm import Model, TransientModel, AbstractModel
   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 5, in <module>
     from ..models import (
   File "/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 2083
      groupby_dict = {gb['groupby']: gb for gb in annotated_groupbys}
```

This error clearly indicates that python 2.6 version is being run (dict comprehensions were introduced in 2.7). And anything I tried, let to same outcome, I either got different error or apache still runs version 2.6.

My configuration:

site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName some.eu
    ServerAlias *.some.eu
    WSGIDaemonProcess oe user=user group=some_group processes=2 python-path=/opt/odoo/odoo/ display-name=apache-odoo
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/odoo/openerp-wsgi.py
    WSGIProcessGroup oe
    ErrorLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-access.log combined
    <Directory /opt/odoo/odoo>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My wsgi configuration file:

```
import sys
import os
import site
#Activate virtualenv
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/opt/odoo/venv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))

site.addsitedir('/opt/odoo/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
sys.path.append("/opt/odoo/odoo")
import openerp


#----------------------------------------------------------
# Common
#----------------------------------------------------------
openerp.multi_process = True # Nah!

# Equivalent of --load command-line option
openerp.conf.server_wide_modules = ['web']
conf = openerp.tools.config

# Path to the OpenERP Addons repository (comma-separated for
# multiple locations)

conf['addons_path'] = '/path/to/addons/'
```

Activating virtualenv in wsgi file seems to do nothing. If I change in apache site configuration `python-path` to `/opt/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`, then I start getting different error saying that run time version is 2.6 and compiletime version is 2.7. Like this:

```
/opt/odoo/odoo/openerp/osv/orm.py:2: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 2.7 of module 'lxml.etree' does not match runtime version 2.6
```

Does anyone have any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution for this (reference that helped me solve it http://jamesseibel.com/blog/?p=45).

First I removed old mod_wsgi files:

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi*
```

Then downloaded and installed mod_wsgi this way:

```
wget https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/master.zip
unzip master
cd mod_wsgi-master
sudo ./configure --with-python=/path/to/bin/python2.7
sudo LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make
sudo make install
```

Now it runs on python2.7

Comment: You can also specify the virtual env location on the apache configuration file as WSGIDaemonProcess python-home=path-to-your-venv